# Trouble importing BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, module, importerror

I've unpacked BeautifulSoup into c:\python2.6\lib\site-packages, which is in `sys.path`, but when I enter `import BeautifulSoup` I get an import error saying no such module exists. Obviously I'm doing something stupid... what is it?

Comment: Without the actual error, we can only guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have more than one python version installed? Check the version you are running.

Also, I found using `easy_install` worked well for installing BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I had to restart IDLE before it would pick up the change